# Does TLS version have a relationship with cellular communication technology?

Tags: ssl, embedded, gsm, gprs

I am a user of Telit GE910-QUAD V3 modem (2G). The below table explains the Telit cellular modems and the TLS protocols they support.

```
Product     SSLV3    TLSV1.0    TLSV1.1    TLSV1.2
 (2G)        N/A       YES        N/A        N/A
 (3G)        YES       YES        YES        N/A
 (4G)        YES       YES        YES        YES
```

After seeing this, I doubt whether cellular technology (2G/3G/4G) plays any role in choosing the TLS version. Just for example, with 2G where data bandwidth and latency are poor, it might not be possible to use higher TLS versions.

Is there any reason why Telit 2G modems don't support higher TLS versions?

Comment: This is a question for the product vendor, not SO.  It is off-topic I believe.

Comment: Note that if the modem (and mobile carrier) support TCP connections, you can implement any normal TLS scheme you want by asking the modem for a TCP connection and doing your own TLS on top, rather than asking the modem to do the TLS for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason that TLS 1.2 can not be run over 2G networks if TLS 1.0 can because these protocols are almost the same. My guess is that the 2G, 3G and 4G modems where simply created at different times and only the newer products support the newer TLS versions simply because these versions were not yet released or not seen as important at the time the software for the older modems was created.