# How to implement TLS 1.2 for GSM module Sim900a?

Tags: ssl, tls1.2, gsm

Note that if the modem (and mobile carrier) support TCP connections, you can implement any normal TLS scheme you want by asking the modem for a TCP connection and doing your own TLS on top, rather than asking the modem to do the TLS for you. – Chris Stratton Oct 9 '17 at 21:52

[Does TLS version have a relationship with cellular communication technology?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642088/does-tls-version-have-a-relationship-with-cellular-communication-technology)

How to implement it ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am trying to use wolfSSL but not able to configure it.